# Is it possible to configure custom config section in ARM template

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

I have created a custom configuration section for a service that is to be deployed to Azure in an app service. I know how to add app settings to the app service configuration. However, I can't find information about how to handle custom configuration sections. Is this something that is supported in Azure ARM templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to override custom section via the Azure App Service ARM API. Instead, this is something you do by simply deploying the right `web.config` file to your Web App.

Comment: That is what I more or less expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

via ARM template NO.

where as one cam make use of [FTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/powershell-deploy-ftp) and add the required changes on post Deploy or make all the required changes on pre deploy. :)